# How to prove the zero product property?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The zero product property states that $ab = 0$ if and only if $a = 0$ or $b = 0$. Is there any way to prove that it only works for these cases?

This question might seem odd and obvious but curiosity for a proof for this arose from a thought I had some days ago. Namely, if $a^2 + b^2 = 0$, then both a and b had to be equal to 0. Then I realised that this only holds if an and b are real numbers since any answer of the form $a = bi$ also satisfies that equation.

That’s my question. Is there any way to prove that the zero product property holds for all numbers?

Comment: It is also true for complex numbers, that $ab=0$ implies either $a=0$ or $b=0$. It has nothing to do with the sum of two squares.

Comment: Yes, @DietrichBurde that helps, thanks!

Comment: This property holds in rings without zero divisors (integral domains) , in particular in fields.